# VBA Loop Copy, paste and do other VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I am relatively new with looping and trying to learn on my existing macro. I am struggling to even start with I feel like a simplistic approach. I have a range of data starting in one workbook on B6 and the list could go forever. What I wanted my loop to do is:

1. copy B6
2. go to another workbook paste it in a cell
3. run another VBA
4. copy and paste the data #3 kicks out that uses #2's value into #1 workbook another sheet
5. Loop and go to B7 starting all over. One change is after B7 is done it will paste below the data already pasted in #4 previously.

Comment: ' Run Values loop and paste to DATA ALL
i = 1
Do Until Workbooks("MAIN").Sheets("Main").Range("Values").Offset(i, 0) = ""
Cusips = Workbooks("MAIN").Sheets("Main").Range("Values").Offset(i, 0)
Workbooks("RUN").Activate
Sheets("RUN").Activate
Range("F1VALUE") = Values
DATA ALLALLV
Range("A11:X11").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("DATA ALL").Activate
With Sheets("DATA ALL").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With

i = i + 1
Loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would need to do this with more than one VBA procedure in one Workbook.

In Workbook#1 I would have a subroutine that started like this:

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook, wb3 as workbook
Dim iRow1 as Long, iRow2 as Long, iRow3 as long
Dim data1 as Variant, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet, ws3 as Worksheet

set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
set wb2 = ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open  <Your workbook filename>
set wb3 = ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open  <Your other workbook filename>
set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("MySheet1")
set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("MySheet2")
set ws3 = wb3.Worksheets("MySheet3")

iRow1 = 6
iRow2 = 1
Do while len(ws1.cells(iRow1, 2)) > 0
    data1 = ws1.cells(iRow1, 2)
    ws2.cells(iRow2, 1) = data1
    iRow2 = iRow2 + 1

    [Rest of Your Code]

    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
```

With all of the workbooks open and everything explicitly referenced there is no need to run multiple VBA procedures or worry about what data is being copied or used.

I know that Python folks love its weak typing, but if you take advantage of VBA's strong typing and object association, then programming will be a breeze and the person that comes along after to maintain your program will be much happier.

Comment: So I meant to paste my VBA when I posted my original post. This is what I came up with. not as pretty as yours and sloppy. Issue I am facing is if my values start with "0" or has an "E" in it its messing with the data. "0" gets cut off and the "E" values turn into scientific format.

Comment: If you copy directly from one cell to another then Excel might try and figure out what your data is and incorrectly think it is a number when it is a string.  But if you Dim a string variable and set that variable to the contents of the first cell, and then set the contents of the second cell using the String variable then Excel won't try to outsmart you and copy it over to the other sheet as a number.